# How to manage the output page in Angular JS - routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs

My project was built on PHP and has some pages on Angular JS. There are three types of accounts in system. Authorization system is based on PHP/Mysql.

For each account I have `personal.html` template. When user is logged via account(1) I need to show him template `/public/html/personal.html` from route, if account(2) - template `/public/html/personal2.html` .etc. So, path `/profile/personal/:type` is the same for each.

How I can manage this accounts pages with a good level of security?

I use `routeProvider`:

```
$routeProvider

        .when('/profile/personal/:type', {
             templateUrl: '/public/html/personal.html',
             controller: 'ProfileController'
  })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - use routeProvider "when" variables to construct templateUrl name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637999/angularjs-use-routeprovider-when-variables-to-construct-templateurl-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function as templateUrl parameter and use it to select the template for the current account type:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/profile/personal/:type', {
        templateUrl: function(params)  {
            switch(params.type) {
                case 1:
                    return: '/public/html/personal1.html';
            }
        },
        controller: 'ProfileController'
    });
```

Comment: But user can to call `/public/html/personal1.html` dirrectly and get this template.

Comment: That's correct, but you can't change that in your javascript application. If you want to prevent the user from accessing the template of other account types, you need to do this on the server side (return a 403 and use it in your angular application to redirect to an error page).

Comment: Can I use factory inside `$routeProvider` that get variable `type` for `:type`