# Why we are using $stateparams in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have seen this coding in Angular JS.

`templateUrl: function($stateParams)` can you explain me about this `stateparams`, its working.

Comment: $stateParams are part of `ui-router` anglular library, an alternative to Angular routing library `$route` and `$routeParams`.

Comment: Usage of $stateParams is similar to one with simple $routeParams. Check this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637999/angularjs-use-routeprovider-when-variables-to-construct-templateurl-name/20638340#20638340 Briefly, it allows to construct template url dynamically depending on route/state parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081397/ui-router-stateparams-vs-state-params) is the link from previous asked question for you hope this will help you to understand your confusion in more details,